# It it possible to change the from address when using sendEmail?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm wondering if there are any options for changing the FROM address of an email sent using MailApp.sendEmail.

I've built a form that's published as a Web App. Students fill out and submit the form, and receive an email. I see how to change the email's reply-to address and sender name. I know that the email's using my address as the From address since I'm the script's owner and the app runs as me.

Is there any way to set the From address to belong to another person, in this case, the instructor? I'm assuming one way to accomplish this is to make him the script owner and walk him through re-publishing the app for us, but I'd rather not hand that over to him. (From what I've seen, only the script owner can publish the script.)

In other words, I want the From address to represent the client the script is being created for, not the programmer who's writing it.

I understand that it's not a desirable feature to allow a script to send email from anyone under the sun. I'm just wondering if anyone has a recommendation for how to solve my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google is not flexible on this one - the only "from" address that you can see is the one belonging to the user whose authority is running the script.

Instead of running as "the programmer", you can use a "robot" google account, something like `DepartmentRobot@ourdomain.com`. You can develop your scripts as yourself, then republish them from the robot.

Within a Google Apps Domain, your admin can create this psuedo-user and edit the settings to hide them from the Google Apps Directory, if that's desireable.

The email that the students receive won't be from their instructor, but it won't be from you, either.

Comment: You can actually use any email that is set up as an alias of the account running the script, by using {from: 'otheremail@example.com'} in the optional parameters. This doesn't solve the use case requested here, but it's good to know.

Comment: `{from: 'one-of-my-aliases@host.com'}` doesn't have any effect for me and isn't documented at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app :-(

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "republish" the script from the robot account?

Comment: Just to clarify: to use the 'from:' parameter you *must* use GmailApp.sendEmail. MailApp.sendEmail will not work. Also the owner of the sheet *must* add the email address you want to use as an alias manually in GMail's setting screen.

Answer (score 23):

If you use GMailApp.sendMail (instead of MailApp.sendEmail) you can specify a from as an optional additional parameter:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

I believe you can only specify aliases that you have already configured your Gmail account with.

Comment: Can you confirm this works? I have a legitimate alias setup, and despite using that in the from field, it still comes through from my main account.

Comment: When you click Reply does it populate the field with the correct/expected address?

Comment: Only because I set the replyTo: field (which does seem to work :-)

Comment: I can confirm that works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Yes you can and it's quite easy. Use the log to determine which spot in the array your alias is if you have multiple aliases. Then to test that you have the right array location use that in the log.

```
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array

GmailApp.sendEmail('person@aol.com','From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});
```

Comment: The request was "sent from another person", an alias is not another person. This is not a valid answer.

Comment: Well if the user is planning to send the e-mail as another person, I assume they would grant them alias rights.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible only if you add an Alias to the Account you want to send the Mail from.

**important:** the alias should be added **manually** to the desired account (in Gmail go to "settings", then "Account" then "Send as")

When you do that, you have to use the GmailApp method in your Script called 'GmailApp.SendEmail()'.

First you have to read the Alias from the Gmail account:

`var myAliases = GmailApp.getAliases();`
let's assume that you have just one alias, so the first alias will be in the indexed 0 -> `myAliases[0]`
in this case you can use the method like this:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail('recipient@yourdomain.con', 'subject', 'body', {from: myAliases[0], name:'Name of the Alias'});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

To further build on @RAWdaMedia and @mickolasjae answers, if you want to send html email using an alias email, you can do so like this.

```
// this should contain data to be put in the variable in your html
var data = [data1, data2];
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('your-html-file-name');

html.data = data;
var template = html.evaluate().getContent();

var subjectLine = "Your subject line";
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()

// this line sends the email using alias email
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subjectLine, template, {from: aliases[0], htmlBody: template});
```

A few things to note:

1. In your Gmail setting, make sure the email alias that you want to use is not marked as default
2. Check the index of the email alias that you want to use if you have more than one and change the index of `aliases` accordingly, so it might be `aliases[1]` or `aliases[2]`

Comment: I was able to leave the alias marked as default and send it using the 0th index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think this might be useful to your question.
I have looked for hours for a solution where a totally stranger can send mail on your behalf but through google script but it didn't work.

Though you can change code and put entire code in if loop where If particular sheet's particular cell has particular word your program will run or Exit.

if program run it at the end you can put command to clear that cell.

then you can instruct user to set A1 of Sheet1 to "Send"
parallelly set time driven trigger to run every minute.

so with in a minute of submission you will get mail from your ID and guess what this time person doesn't even need to login google account!

You can ask users to check if someone else is online on top right of sheet. if it is case they can come back later. Method is bit crude but it works.

I'm new here. just trying to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to build on [chrisb's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640714/4806936), but I am not allowed to comment yet...

As chrisb said:

1. create an allias in your account just for the form.
2. Use Gmail.App to send the email "from" the alias that you created.

Then write Google Apps script to process emails sent to that alias such that emails from the instructor appear in your inbox, but emails from anyone else get forwarded to the instructor with the "replyTo" field set to whoever sent the email.