# Configure Sender, Reply-To for MailApp

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I developed a "Leave Request" form app for client. It's able to trigger a custom email to requestor. It's working but not perfect (as link below)
[Actual screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oiJxjFS17zNTxVOH_hEwBo6m5qkziXMs/view?usp=drivesdk)

From the screenshot, 
sender is my developer account; reply-to is my client domain; recipient is my petronel test account. I understand the sender shown as my email because I given consensus while I develop script. But in actual production, it shouldn't behave such.

How could I enhance following items?

- Sender = support@client-domain.com (not an individual GSuite account)
- Recipients = any @gmail/g-suite users
- Developer the logic using my developer account and later transfer the ownership to client (@jtjtechnology.com) and not to an individual?

Thanks for the guidance in million. I been reading Google's Bible but still count figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't configure sender (as far as I know) but instead you can set `noReply: true;` this will show sender as `noreply@domain`. If you want to get replies also then you can set that in `replyTo` like `replyTo: support@domain`

Recipients can be easily set by passing as argument to `sendEmail()`
If you set `noReply: true;` then developer(who have given consensus) will be masked, so no need to transfer ownership and all.

But `noReply` works only for GSuite users, if you're not one of them then checkout this out [It it possible to change the from address when using sendEmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885290/it-it-possible-to-change-the-from-address-when-using-sendemail)

For full reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options
check options parameter

Comment: I have studied the API and aware that Reply-To is define-able. My only concern is in corporate world, it's not nice to show username@vendor-domain. com but rather support@client-domain.com.

Hence, setting a support@client-domain.com as sender is almost a must have in my context and I believe other clients need so. 

Just I have no luck in getting the solutions from Google Bible